# How does below Java code work? Is it a kind of the implicit type conversion?

Tags: java, types, casting

I saw the following Java code in one project:

```
SimpleDateFormat dtFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd");
long dt = weatherDataPerDay.getLong(JSON_KEY_DATETIME);
String result = dtFormater.format(dt * 1000).toString();
```

Firstly, above code works. I checked the definition of SimpleDateFormat and all its predecessors but didn't find a method like `format(long time)`.

I only got 2 methods that accepted 1 parameter. They were

- `format(Object object)`
- `format(Date date)`.

So far as I know, Java only supports the implicit type conversion among the numeric data types and only from small data type to big data type.

So I can't explain why above code works.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Great thanks, @pvg!!! So the path is long -->(Boxing) Long -->(is-a) Object --> format(Object object). Right?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind format is a pretty funky api - the particular class you're using really only accepts subclasses of Number and Date. These are checked at runtime by the implementation.

Comment: @pvg gotcha! and thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have noticed, the class `SimpleDateFormat` has 2 methods `format`: `format(Object object)` and `format(Date date)`. Here as `dt` is a `long`, `dt * 1000` will be a `long` too and thanks to [**autoboxing**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), it will be automatically converted as an instance of the wrapper class `Long` such that it will finally call `format(Object object)` with our `Long` instance as parameter.

The method `format(Object object)` will call behind the scene [`DateFormat#format(Object obj, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition fieldPosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.lang.Object-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.text.FieldPosition-) which only accepts as stated into the javadoc a `Number` or a `Date` as type of the parameter `obj` otherwise an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown.

And when the parameter `obj` is of type `Number` which is the case here as `Long` is sub-class of `Number`, it automatically creates a new `Date` instance with `new Date(((Number)obj).longValue())` which means that it excepts the `Number` to be a total amount of the milliseconds since *January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT*.

Answer (score 1):

consider this program:

```
public class A {
  public static void f(Object o) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    f(1);
  }
}
```

The output is `java.lang.Integer`. The compiler is seeing that you're passing a primitive value to a method receiving an object. It therefore "boxes" the primitive type into its Object counter part, so the int becomes an `Integer`. As `Integer` is an `Object`, the new instance can be happily passed to the method.